# Golang Websocket (Gorilla) with cookie authentification

Tags: go, cookies, websocket

I'm trying to use gorilla websocket to start the chart.
Authentification middleware working through cookie with JWT token.
All my endpoints through HTTP works, but websocket doesn't.
After reading a lot of topics like [Gorilla websocket with cookie authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324251/gorilla-websocket-with-cookie-authentication) I found that my cookie empty, and my context in the websocket connection also empty. I don't understand why? Can anyone explain me why?
P.S.: I have tried delete upgrader from that handler and cookie and context passed well, but after upgrade connection to websocket protocol it's fails.
Here is my files:
Endpoints:

```golang
func (r *router) routes(engine *gin.Engine) {
    engine.Use(r.handler.VerifyUser())

    engine.POST("/signup", r.handler.CreateUser)
    engine.POST("/signin", r.handler.LoginUser)
    engine.GET("/welcome", r.handler.Welcome)
    engine.GET("/logout", r.handler.Logout)

    engine.POST("/ws/createRoom", r.wsHandler.CreateRoom)
    engine.GET("/ws/joinRoom/:roomId", r.wsHandler.JoinRoom)
}
```

ws_handler

```golang
func (h *Handler) JoinRoom(c *gin.Context) {
    claims := c.Request.Context().Value("jwt").(models.Claims) //couldn't find value with "jwt" key
    fmt.Println(claims.ID, claims.Name)
    cookie, err := c.Cookie("chartJWT") // allways err no cookie
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("no cookie, error:%v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("cookie: %+v\n", cookie)
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }
```

middleware:

```golang
func (h *handler) VerifyUser() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        notAuth := []string{"/signup", "/signin"}
        requestPath := c.Request.URL.Path

        for _, val := range notAuth {
            if val == requestPath {
                c.Next()
                return
            }
        }

        token, err := c.Cookie("chartJWT")
        if err != nil {
            c.Redirect(http.StatusPermanentRedirect, signinPage)
        }

        claims, ok := validateToken(token)
        if !ok {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": errors.New("invalid token")})
            return
        }

        c.Request = c.Request.WithContext(context.WithValue(c.Request.Context(), "jwt", *claims))

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

All other endpoints works, if you need any other code just let me know. I don't want to make my question more complex, as i think it's pretty simple, but i misunderstand something (
Thanks for any help and advises.

P.S.: if i turn off middleware everything works as expects.

Update:
Added validate and generate funcs

```golang
func validateToken(jwtToken string) (*models.Claims, bool) {
    claims := &models.Claims{}

    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(jwtToken, claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(config.SECRETKEY), nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return claims, false
    }

    if !token.Valid {
        return claims, false
    }

    return claims, true
}

func (h *handler) generateTokenStringForUser(id, name string) (string, error) {
    // Create the JWT claims, which includes the username and expiry time
    claims := models.Claims{
        ID:   id,
        Name: name,
        RegisteredClaims: jwt.RegisteredClaims{
            Issuer:    id,
            ExpiresAt: jwt.NewNumericDate(time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour)),
        },
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claims)
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(config.SECRETKEY))
    return tokenString, err
}
```

added signin func where i added cookie with JWT string

```golang
func (h *handler) LoginUser(c *gin.Context) {
    var input models.LoginUserReq

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&input); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    res, err := h.Service.LoginUser(context.Background(), &input)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    token, err := h.generateTokenStringForUser(res.ID, res.Name)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    c.SetCookie("chartJWT", token, 60*60*24, "/", "localhost", false, true)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"user": res})
}
```

Update after help:
The problem was in my Postman setup request where i didn't specify cookie right.

Comment: @CharlieTumahai yes, if i didn't comment lines with cookie and the context it willn't work. But if I comment these lines websocket works. I think that the problem in my "VerifyUser() " method. But i don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to help to figure out what was wrong. First, I simplified a little bit your example just to focus only on the relevant parts. If you need something omitted just let me know and I'll update the answer. First, let me start with the `JWT` token generation/verification which is made within the local `auth` package.

#### `auth/auth.go` file

```golang
package auth

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt"
)

func ValidateToken(jwtToken string) (*jwt.MapClaims, error) {
    // parse the token
    token, err := jwt.Parse(strings.Replace(jwtToken, "Bearer ", "", 1), func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC)
        if !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }
        return []byte("Abcd1234!!"), nil
    })
    // err while parsing the token
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // token valid
    var claims jwt.MapClaims
    var ok bool
    if claims, ok = token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
        return &claims, nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("token not valid")
}

func GenerateToken(username, password string) (string, error) {
    // TODO: here you can add logic to check against a DB
    //...

    // create a new token by providing the cryptographic algorithm
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)

    // set default/custom claims
    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour * 3).Unix()
    claims["username"] = username
    claims["password"] = password

    tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte("Abcd1234!!"))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return tokenString, nil
}
```

Now, let's move to the middleware part.

#### `middlewares/middlewares.go` file

```golang
package middlewares

import (
    "net/http"

    "websocketauth/auth"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func VerifyUser() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        notAuth := []string{"/signin"}
        requestPath := c.Request.URL.Path
        for _, val := range notAuth {
            if val == requestPath {
                c.Next()
                return
            }
        }

        token, err := c.Cookie("chartJWT")
        if err != nil {
            c.Redirect(http.StatusPermanentRedirect, "/signin")
        }

        claims, err := auth.ValidateToken(token)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }

        c.Set("jwt", *claims)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

To be able to upload something in the context you should use `c.Set(key, value)` method. Now, let's move to the handlers.

#### `handlers/handlers.go` file

```golang
package handlers

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "websocketauth/auth"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var Upgrader websocket.Upgrader

type LoginUserReq struct {
    Username string `json:"username" binding:"required"`
    Password string `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}

func LoginUser(c *gin.Context) {
    var input LoginUserReq
    if err := c.ShouldBind(&input); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    // I don't know what you do within the handler.Service.LoginUser() method

    token, err := auth.GenerateToken(input.Username, input.Password)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    c.SetCookie("chartJWT", token, 60*60*24, "/", "localhost", false, true)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"user": token})
}

func JoinRoom(c *gin.Context) {
    claims := c.MustGet("jwt").(jwt.MapClaims)
    fmt.Println("username", claims["username"])
    fmt.Println("password", claims["password"])
    ws, err := Upgrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    chartToken, err := c.Cookie("chartJWT")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("chartToken", chartToken)
    _ = ws
}
```

Missing parts, such as the `handler.Service.LoginUser()` method are skipped due to the fact that I don't know what they do. To properly read stuff from context, you've to use the `c.MustGet(key)` method.

#### `main.go` file

```golang
package main

import (
    "websocketauth/handlers"
    "websocketauth/middlewares"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func main() {
    handlers.Upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    }
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)
    r := gin.Default()

    r.Use(middlewares.VerifyUser())
    r.GET("/join-room", handlers.JoinRoom)
    r.POST("/signin", handlers.LoginUser)

    r.Run(":8000")
}
```

This is the set up logic. Nothing worth mentioning here.
Let me know if you still need other help, thanks!

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i think you misunderstand the problem, or its is my bad english. The problem was that middleware (VerifyUser func) should check if the user already logged in, and if he didn't should be redirected to the "/signin" page.
In your example your middleware just add cookie to everyone to all your requests. My problem is that websocket connection fails because have no cookies.

Comment: This was not clear to me in your question. Please edit the question and add the code for the `validateToken` function as I don't know which checks you perform.

Comment: BTW, my code was only a simplification to show you how to add cookies within the middleware. You should be able to easily adjust it to meet your own requirements. Please answer the above question so I can edit the response. Thanks

Comment: i have added additional funcs that you have been asked. PLease check and thank you for your help.

Comment: just tried all your code and receive the same error in postman as i had:
```
Could not connect to ws://localhost:8000/join-room
Error: Unexpected server response: 404
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/join-room
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: u5AdwYjIV8XlmFHmOLACFA==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: localhost:8000
Response Headers
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2023 09:14:13 GMT
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254011/discussion-between-ossan-and-1oko).